# How to return an array with cumulative values in a recursive method

Tags: ruby, recursion

I am attempting to take two values `times` and `number` and return an array of `number` repeated `times` times. Here is an example:

```
replicate(3, 5) # => [5, 5, 5]
```

Here is my attempt 1:

```
@array = []

def replicate(times, number)
  return [] if times <= 0
  @array << number 
  replicate(times - 1, number)
  @array
end
```

When I run each test case once in isolation, I pass everything. However, when I run them all at once, it fails; `@array` contains all the values for every test case and `@array` will look like this at the end of the entire test suite:

```
@array # => [5, 5, 5, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2]
```

Here is implementation two:

```
def replicate(times, number)
  return [] if times <= 0
  array = []
  array << number 
  replicate(times - 1, number)
  array
end
```

This will return only one value because recursion will create a local copy for every run.

How can I return an array that will make the test cases pass? I can't use global or instance variables, or a local copy of an array. Is there something I can use in between?

Comment: Try passing array into your recursive function defination.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In this case there's no need to keep an accumulator either as an instance variable or an argument. All you need to do is concatenate the result from this call (which will be an array with a single element, i.e. `[ number ]`) with the result of subsequent calls:

```
def replicate(times, number)
  return [] if times <= 0
  [ number ] + replicate(times - 1, number)
end
```

If you wanted to use an accumulator, you could do it this way:

```
def replicate(times, number, accum=[])
  return accum if times <= 0
  replicate(times - 1, number, accum + [ number ])
end
```

(Note that you could use `accum << number` as well, but personally I prefer to treat data structures as immutable when writing recursive functions—because, well, it's a capital-F function and functions shouldn't have side-effects.)

Comment: This is a better answer.

Comment: Thanks, @NicNilov. Your solution was good as well. Sorry someone downvoted it. :(

Answer (score 5):

Pass your accumulator array to recursive calls:

```
def replicate(times, number, array=[])
   return [] if times <= 0
   array << number
   replicate(times - 1, number, array)
   array
end

replicate(3, 5)
=> [5, 5, 5]
```

Comment: This is a pattern frequently seen. Is there a name for this?

Comment: Accumulative recursion is one way to call it

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply do :

```
[number]*times
```

Example :

```
$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > [1]*5
 => [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
```